# sudo mkdir ask for password?

Tags: bash, sudo, mkdir

OK i googled a lot but something just  doesn't add-up:

in terminal i use this code: `sudo mkdir /Volumes/aNewFolder`
but then the terminal asks me for my user password. why? and also - how can i pass the password so terminal wont stop and wait for user's input?
this is silly but i cant seem to fix it or to find it on the web; all i want is to `mkdir` without having to input my password directly...
i didnt really tried anything cause i cant seem to find any info about it. 
im pretty sure that the solution is easy and im missing something. im new to unix and bash but `mkdir`is a very basic thing, right?
help, please?

edit: forgot to say that i thought `expect` could help but all i see is how to use it with `ssh`...

mac user

Comment: `sudo` will ask for the user password everytime as it executes a command with root privileges. You need it along with `mkdir` if the user doesn't have enough rights to create a directory in the specified path. There is no way around it, except from granting more privileges to your user. There are plenty information about `sudo` and `permissions` on the internet

Comment: If you don't want to enter a password you need to properly configure `sudo` so that your user has permission to run mkdir as root without a password. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/sudoers.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/sudoers

Comment: sudo is asking for password, because it is his job... use mkdir without sudo, and you will not need any password. using sudo can be dangerous, so, don't use it until you will understand it's purpose.

Comment: @Zander Rootman maybe i wasn't clear: i dont mind providing the password. or give up the use of `sudo`. but i want the script to run without interruptions (i.e. prompted to provide password). so what i really need is a way to pass the password to the `mkdir` command.
btw if this is "off-topic" please dont unvote me - just tell me how and i'll redirect the question to superuser.com

Comment: @zook2005: The password is given to the `sudo` command. `mkdir` doesn't need, and is incapable of receiving, a password (it just needs to have the necessary privileges in the first place -- and it's `sudo`'s job to provide them).

Comment: @KeithThompson im not sure im following. i understand that `mkdir` cant take password. ok. but i still dont know how overcome this - when i try to `mkdir` with `sudo` i need to provide password. when i try to `mkdir` without `sudo` i get perrmision denied. so - how can i `mkdir` without interference?

Comment: @zook2005: You need to use `sudo mkdir ...`, and you need to configure `sudo` so it doesn't ask for your password. The method is explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43135/10454). Be aware that this is a security risk; it gives anyone with access to your account full root access to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo = super user do`.. You need to give your terminal session the password for the super user, to have "administrative" access.

Depending where you're trying to make a new directory, you don't always need to add "sudo" to your command.

If say you were trying to make a new directory in your home folder.. i.e.: `mkdir ~/myNewDir`
you won't need to add a `sudo` to it, because your home folder is owned by your user.

But let's say you were trying to make a new folder in `/etc/ssh/`, an area where your user does not have read/write access to, you would need to append the command with `sudo`, to inform the CLI that a or the, super user is going to perform the task.

Hope it helps.

If you really want to skip the password authentication every time, you could type:
`sudo -su root` give it root users password, and from that point on forward (and only for that terminal session) will the user root be used (see it as super user), and your commands will run without any authentication (Since root user has read/write access across the system). I wouldn't recommend doing this, if you're not sure about what you're doing.